# Qt crash of critical QLogger QMessageLogger syntax not understood.

Tags: c++, qt, crash

i have a code where i get crash when i try to call Qt QMessageLogger critical, when i use debug log it works, but when i use critical log it crashes. Following the definitions i got to this code; i was wondering about the meaning of pointer without name and {} instead of ";" in the definition of noDebug method as follows:

```
void debug(const char *msg, ...) const Q_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PRINTF(2, 3);
void noDebug(const char *, ...) const Q_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PRINTF(2, 3)
{}
void warning(const char *msg, ...) const Q_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PRINTF(2, 3);
void critical(const char *msg, ...) const Q_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PRINTF(2, 3);
```

The full header is published in this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qt/+/master/common/include/QtCore/qlogging.h). you can find the code above at lines 89 to 94.
Can this be the reason of the crash i have. when i simply change critical by debug there is no crash:

```
qDebug() << "Unknown  widget type (" << type << ")"; // Works
qCritical() << "Unknown widget type::: (" << type << ")"; // Crashes
```

Can you tell me if this make sense because i do not understand the syntax
thanks

Comment: noone has a proposition?

Comment: not really, no. You could try to implement your own message handler to find out whether it happens before or after that point (See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler)

Comment: @Felix thank you for the reply. i don't know though whether Qt is rebuiling its own libs when i rebuild. i mean the changes i  do on qt own code would those changes also be rebuild

Comment: when i try to post this question on qt forum, i get connection problem on their site "https://forum.qt.io/category/10/general-and-desktop".

Comment: You are aware that [qCritical()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qCritical) "exits if the environment variable QT_FATAL_CRITICALS is not empty"? That might look like a crash, but is just the expected behavior.

Comment: thank you @SteakOverflow i've checked that variable and i don't see it defined. and to the run batch file i add "set QT_FATAL_CRITICALS=" and "set QT_FATAL_CRITICALS=xx" for both conditions, i always get the crash.